# Suppress Hibernate deprecated messages in a Log4j2 properties file

Tags: hibernate, logging, warnings, log4j2, deprecated

I am trying to get rid of these error messages appearing in our logs / console out:

`[WARN ] [2023-05-09 11:19:46.567] [deprecation.createCriteria:1832] - HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead`

I am able to do this using an XML configuration file for log4j2 using either of these two methods:

```
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.deprecation" additivity="false" level="WARN">
        <RegexFilter regex=".*HHH90000022.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        </Logger>
```

```
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.deprecation" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
        </Logger>
```

However, we use .properties files for this service (any many others) so ideally I need to find the exact equivalent of the above but for a .properties file.

Apparently with log4j this was achieved like so:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.orm.deprecation=error

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error
```

But the syntax is different for log4j2 and I can't find any specific examples - can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite figured out how to make this work with the logger, since for some odd reason the `additivity=false` seems to remove all logging for that logger.

But you can also set the filter on the appender, which is acceptable in my situation. My `log4j2.properties` looks like this:

```
rootLogger.level=WARN
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LogToConsole

appenders=ConsoleAppender
appender.ConsoleAppender.type=Console
appender.ConsoleAppender.name=LogToConsole
appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.pattern=[%p] %c{1} %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss,SSS 'UTC'}{GMT} %m%n
appender.ConsoleAppender.filter.HibernateDeprecationFilter.type=RegexFilter
appender.ConsoleAppender.filter.HibernateDeprecationFilter.regex=.*HHH90000022.*
appender.ConsoleAppender.filter.HibernateDeprecationFilter.onMatch=DENY
appender.ConsoleAppender.filter.HibernateDeprecationFilter.onMismatch=NEUTRAL
```

Please do note that this will pass all logging for the appender through the filter, not just the Hibernate logging.